# What property of USB battery packs allows them to simultaneously output power while receiving power?

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging, charge, discharge

Why do some USB battery packs, usually cheaper ones* allow for charging and discharging but some do not? Is there any problem with doing this?

Context: I want to power a phone by USB battery pack, and at the same time charge the battery pack with a small solar panel unit, thus creating a poor-mans USP setup.

* as I've observed myself and [elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3hm00e/usb_battery_packs_that_can_chargedischarge_at_the/)

**For clarity: I do not want to charge and discharge a *battery*, I want to charge (or at least leave plugged in) and charge another device from a *battery pack*. Different thing!**

Comment: It's physically impossible to charge and discharge a battery at the same time. What's probably happening is that the supply is providing enough power to supply the device as well as charge the battery.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there any harm in doing this though? I've noticed it can work very effectively - i.e. if a phone is full and will not draw more power, the pack itself will begin to charge instead. This seems like a great feature and I wonder if there is some drawback since better batteries don't do it.

Comment: What's "better" about the ones that don't?

Comment: I say _better_ meaning, more expensive. For example, Anker batteries just won't output at all if they are plugged in (from what I have seen).

Comment: Downvoted due to people not reading/understanding the question. I am not trying to charge and discharge a battery!

Comment: Just like an online UPS: use input power to power the output, use the rest to charge. If the input power is guaranteed to be greater than the load power, then you won't discharge the battery. Actually all smart phones works this way.

Comment: What is unclear about what OP is asking for? He wants to have a $200 solar-charging backup system out of $10 USB power bank. What essentially needs to be explained is why the solar-backed UPS is so much more expensive than USB power bank.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, but this would seem to be a design choice. The simplest way to build one of these things is to have a "T" shaped connection between the battery, its charger, and the boost converter for the output. However, that means the charger can't tell whether current is flowing into the battery or to the load. This makes both current limiting and charge termination more difficult.

It may be the case that running something from the pack output causes the battery to go through lots of tiny charge/discharge cycles. This is bad for its life. I suspect that the expensive ones regard this as bad and prevent it while the cheap ones don't care.

There's also the question of what happens if you try to draw more current from the pack than the charger is supplying: you'll definitely have charge-discharge cycles then.

The other cheap solution is a large Schottky diode from input to output. This results in the output voltage being slightly less than the input voltage. Again something that cheap makes may not care about.

See [Teardown 1](https://cpldcpu.com/2014/03/31/external-usb-battery/), or [Teardown 2](http://goughlui.com/2013/07/14/teardown-unbranded-5000mah-usb-charger-packpower-bank/)

Comment: There are single chip single cell USB UPS-like PMICs like LTC3556 which solves your "T connection" problem.

Comment: One approach is to use a single bidirectional synchronous buck converter for both charging the battery of the power bank from an USB host, and (operating in reverse) discharging the battery to an USB slave. Some monolithic chips already do this, e.g. http://www.linear.com/docs/46542

Answer (score 0):

Any battery can only be charging or discharging at any one time.  There is no such thing as simultaneous charging/discharging.

It is possible for a entire unit that contains a battery and charger allows for using the battery voltage while charging.  Whether the battery charges or discharges during such operation depends on how much current the charger is providing and how much current the load is drawing.  The battery current will be (charger current) - (load current).  If that is positive, the battery is being charged.  If that is negative, the battery is being discharged.

Comment: As I said in the question, this is explicitly referring to battery packs, not batteries. I even highlighted this in bold to avoid being told the same thing again. The behaviour of different battery packs is not as consistent as you claim - I can plug in the same charger and device and get different behaviours from different packs. My question is: why?

Comment: @Ben: Whether you have a single cell or multiple cells in parallel/series in a "pack" doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you able to answer the question: why are some packs/units/collections of multiple cells are able to perform a function whereby if they are plugged in and receiving power they are able to continue to output power, but some are not?

Comment: It's a design choice. If you have only one port on a device you can either plug a charger in or plug in a device to supply power to. With two ports you can do both at the same time - if you chose to allow it and the supply has enough capacity for both.

Comment: @Finbarr What factors would lead to those design choices, assuming there are always enough ports?

Comment: Cost, marketing, requirements specified, any number of factors - as with most things. As you've seen, it's perfectly possible but some choose to do it, others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking why not all "battery packs" perform full power management function. Consider challenges of the task you are asking for:

You have three power domains, (a) Power input, usually called VIN or VBUS, (b) power output, usually designated as VSYS, and (c) battery VBAT.

To perform full power management to your desire, you have to provide several modes of operations, with automatic switch between them depending on conditions:

1. You have no VBUS. The VSYS  (voltage to your device, usually +5 V to a phone/tablet) is getting from VBAT (normally 3.0 - 3.8 V), so your PMIC must work as **BOOST converter** from VBAT to VSYS;
2. You have VBUS and no phone. As VBUS is usually +5V and above, the PMIC must work as **BUCK converter/charger** from VBUS tyo VBAT, with necessary constant-current/constant voltage mode to properly charge the Li-Ion cell;
3. You have VBUS in and phone (load on VSYS) in. If VBUS sources +5V, the PMIC must have a **DIRECT PATH switch** to bypass the VBUS to VSYS, while maintaining the LiIon charging mode from VBUS to VBAT.

Now consider that VBUS usually have limitations as 500 mA, 900 mA, or else, depending on the source. The PMIC must have an intelligence to limit its consumption while supplying BOTH VSYS and charging VBAT. More, it must somehow balance the output to VSYS (to phone) and VBAT if you want the battery to be alive. If your VBUS comes from a "small solar-powered unit", it likely has no capacity to provide full load to your phone AND, and nothing is left to charge the battery.

Again, to manage the phone charging system, you must advertise to your phone side some capability (provide charger signature on the VSYS end), which is again either 500mA or above. If your "small solar-powered unit" can't provide this, some output must be disabled, VSYS (so your phone won't receive charge), or VBAT (so your bank battery wont't be charged).

Finally, your "small solar-powered unit" likely have some variable output (depending on time of day and overall insolation), so you have to intelligently manage all three power domains, which can be done only by a microprocessor.
To appreciate complexity of the task, you may want to examine the portfolio of PMICs offered by Texas Intruments by looking into [some examples as BQ25xxx family](http://www.ti.com/product/bq25896?keyMatch=bq25896&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything).

Now, do you see why "cheap USB power banks" cannot do what you are asking for? I even believe that there is not a single USB power bank that can do the job you want, and only [quite expensive specialized solar systems](http://www.ruralmfg.com/mall/2_EF01_EN34_B200-Solar.aspx) can.

Comment: Cheap solar-powered USB power banks works in two-ways only, (1) Solar charges battery if no phone connected (takes 3-4 sunny days for full charge), and (2) Solar feeds the phone, and phone charges slowly dropping power demand down to solar capability, and battery seems to draining slowly. https://www.amazon.com/Levin-6000mAh-Portable-Charger-Android/dp/B00JEGLLHM/ref=pd_sbs_107_5